# Ruby GNOME GUIs

Tags: ruby, linux, gtk, gnome

With the recent release of GNOME 3 and Ubuntu moving to Unity, what toolkit should rubyists be using to develop their apps?  I know that there are bindings to GTK2, are these still ok to use?

Comment: I've tried building some GTK, Gnome apps using Ruby. The library is *very* poorly documented and it's incomplete. My general observation has been that Ruby is really useful for web apps and for agile tools. Not much else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still OK to use the GTK 2 bindings - GTK 2 and 3 will be installed in parallel on most desktop distributions for several years yet. That said, you should keep in mind while you're writing your application that you should update it to GTK 3 when those bindings become prevalent. Take a [look](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/gtk-migrating-2-to-3.html) at the differences between GTK 2 and 3 and don't write code that will be hard to port when the time comes.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at visualruby.  It uses GTK2, which has been around for a while, so its stable.  Its specifically designed for making ruby GUIs:

http://visualruby.net

Answer (score 0):

I've heard good things about [ruby shoes](http://shoesrb.com/) although never tried it myself. Maybe you should check it out?